# ruby on rails session information grab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i run in my page this code :

> <% user = User.find(session[:userid]) %>

i get the error :

> line #1 raised:
>
> Couldn't find User without an ID

although i have in my authentification in my sessions_controller this :

```
def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:username],params[:password])
      session[:user_id]= user.id
      session[:language_id]= user.language_id
      User.find(user.id).update_attributes(:last_login => Time.now)
      redirect_to root_path , :notice => (I18n.t :"session.login_success")
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = (I18n.t :"session.error")
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

and the session should contain the userid

Comment: This is probably just a typo when entering your question, but I notice that in one place you have `session[userid]` while in another place you have `session[:user_id]` (note the underscore).

Comment: ah ! i just didn't see it .. i've been working all day and i'm very tired . Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your log-in you set `session[:user_id]`, and you try to find `session[:userid]` (note the spurious underscore). That's why.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is looking for params `session[:user_id]`, but in your views it is `session[:userid]` so it will complain that `session[:user_id]` is `nil`.